# Changing commit message of already pushed repo

Tags: git, github, message, commit

I have accidentally pushed a repo with a wrong commit message. I have followed the solutions provided on internet but it didn't change my commit message. I tried to solve the problem by creating a ReadMe.txt file and pushing it with new commit message like this:

```
git add .
git commit -amend -m 'My New Correct Message'
git push origin master
```

However it didn't change the commit message of rest of the files in my repo.

PS: I have push an eclipse project on github so it has alot of folders and files and I want to change the commit message of all of them.

I found out git isn't pushing all the files and folders that I intend to push with a new message because they haven't been modified and are same as before, therefore I guess I can't update my commit message.

How can I solve this problem?

Regards

Comment: Any error messages?
Once you have pushed you should not amend those commits, because that will replace the commit with a new one.
Are you just pushing to your own repository on github where nobody else is pushing to?
Only in that case you could do `git push --force ...` when you get an error about not being a fast forward without the `--force` option.
Otherwise you should just live with that typo forever.

Comment: Git is then piece of garbage. We can't even change a commit message. BTW no one has forked/pulled my repo yet

Comment: Yes, swearing at software you don't even understand yet is an alternative solution, but will not get you far.

Comment: well this thing sure is very complex. What can be the solution to my situation

Comment: You have to be more specific in your question. So you have made many individual commits and they all have an incorrect commit message?

Comment: Last commits were a try to update or change the wrong message

Comment: At this point I would suggest you take a git tutorial on a sandbox repository. There you could try out `git rebase -i FROM_OLDEST_COMMIT_ID` but make sure you first set your favorite editor e.g. with `export EDITOR=emacs` or `export EDITOR=vi`. http://git-scm.com/documentation is a great resource. You might be interested in http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History specifically.

Answer (score 2):

A history just like what you have only with different [anything] is a different history.  It's very easy to cook those up.  Everybody likes to say scary things about doing that, but all it boils down to is if you're going to switch a ref to a rewritten history you have to tell everybody who might have fetched the older history to refetch the new one and perhaps rebase their work onto it if they have any to rebase.  If that's easy to get right, rewrite is your friend.

There are three main ways to make an altered version of current commits, `amend`, `rebase -i`, and `filter-branch`.  `amend` is for altering a single tip commit, from comments it's apparent you've got more than just one.  If you've only got a handful, say up to a dozen or so?, do `git rebase -i --onto lastgoodcommit lastgoodcommit`, change all the `pick`s to `reword`, and edit the commit messages one by one.  So, say you've got

```
$ git lgdo  # alias for log --graph --decorate --oneline --all
* dea1611 (HEAD, a) -
* e628853 Initial dynamic-selchar
* a4caf1a Can't call InvalidateDi
* cff32b3 Can't call InvalidateDi
* aa8d514 This branch ctd's for s
* 55787bc more refactoring to red
* a0cfdb7 Beginnings of multipage
* 3a8296b Apple-polishing
* 5bbd1ee Okay, the single-displa
* 31c60fe Version 0.0a: basic fun
* ae8379b .
* 6b0edc6 Little light refactorin
* 834cfbf More prep for menu/butt
* e842e61 wip
* 4a1b928 More UI decode/route pr
* b836444 Baseline development
```

and everything after "Apple-polishing" has a bad commit message, you'd do

```
git rebase -i --onto 3a82 3a82    # or :/^Apple :/^Apple
```

and in e.g. vim `:%s,^pick,reword,|wq` to start the cycle.

Once you're done, `git push origin +master`

Answer (score 0):

```
git push origin +master
```

should do the trick. But **CAUTION!**: Do not do that if there are other people depending on your published branch, or you will disrupt their work, forcing them to rebase.

Comment: Will this change the message of all the files and folders in my repo?

Comment: Messages are attached to commits, not to files/folders. Your first two lines changed the message of the last commit. What I have written down will replace the master branch on origin with the master branch on your local repository, so now the last commit will have the new message.

Comment: Well I don't want last commit message to change because I have made many commits to solve this problem. Is there a way to change the message of all the commits or commit of specific number

Comment: Sorry, now I don't understand what you want to do. Please rephrase or wait for someone else.

Comment: is there a way to change the message of all the commits in a repo? Or how can I reupload/push all the files and folders to the repo because git is ignoring them because they are not changed

Comment: Ok. I got confused because the lines you wrote at the beginning only change the message for the last commit, so I thought that was what you wanted. If what you want is to change message for all commits, see help for `git filter-branch`, particularly the --msg-filter option. Then, after filtering the branch, push using the `+` as shown above to replace the branch at origin instead of adding to it.